# How do I get the raw SQL underlying a LINQ query when using Entity Framework CTP 5 "code only"?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, profiling, code-first, ef4-code-only

I've using Entity Framework CTP5 in "code only" mode. I'm running a LINQ query on a object that was return from the database, as the query is running really slowly. Is there any way in which I can get the SQL statement that is being generated from the query?

```
Topic currentTopic =
    (from x in Repository.Topics
     let isCurrent = (x.StoppedAt <= x.StartedAt || (x.StartedAt >= currentTopicsStartedAtOrAfter))
     where x.Meeting.Manager.User.Id == user.Id && isCurrent
     orderby x.StartedAt descending
     select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

The "Repository" property is a descendent of DbContext.

It's a little complicated, as EF can't use my helper methods on the objects, so I'm specifying the logic directly in the query.

So, is there any way I can dump the SQL that will be produced by that LINQ query (e.g. to my log4net repository)?

Comment: I can't help you with the SQL dump, but I'm curious as to why EF can't use your helper methods on the objects. How have you defined the helpers?

Comment: Well, I have a IsCurrent property on the topic, that is defined as "return (StoppedAt <= StartedAt || (DateTime.Now - StartedAt).TotalHours <= ExpirationPeriodHours)". If I use that in the query (i.e. x.IsCurrent), it won't execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd either use SQL Trace to grab the query running on the server directly, or use the Event Tracing for Windows (SQL Profiling) feature out of [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/).

Answer (score 19):

You can try using [Entity Framework tracing provider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx) as [described here](http://jkowalski.com/2010/04/23/logging-sql-statements-in-entity-frameworkcode-first/) (but it is old post for CTP3).

Your other choices are:

- [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) - part of MS SQL Developer tools (in case your DB is SQL Server)
- Intelli trace - only in VS 2010 Ultimate but it doesn't show parameter values
- [Hugati Query Profiler](http://www.huagati.com/L2SProfiler/)
- [Entity framework profiler](http://efprof.com/)

In common EF you can also use `ToTraceString` as @Andy suggested but `DbQuery` in CodeFirst doesn't have this method (or I didn't find it).

**Edit:**

So `DbQuery` doesn't have `ToTraceString` because it is [directly implemented](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/287ed59d-1949-4a0d-a03b-c43a6e8bc480) as `ToString`.

Comment: +1 for .ToString() - took me 15 minutes to find this post and 2 seconds to actually see my query! i like it

Comment: When I use DbQuery.ToString(), the SQL it returns doesn't fill in the parameters.  In other words it contains a bunch of "@p__linq__0".  Am I the only one who sees this?

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me and it is free:

```
public static class DebugExtensions
{
    private static object GetPropertyValue(object o, string Name)
    {
        return o.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public).Where(x => x.Name == Name).First().GetValue(o, null);
    }
    public static string ToTraceString(this IQueryable query)
    {
        var oquery = (ObjectQuery)GetPropertyValue(GetPropertyValue(query, "InternalQuery"), "ObjectQuery");
        return oquery.ToTraceString();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
   var rows = db.Forecasts.Take(1);
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(rows.ToTraceString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting up logging is as easy as:

```
context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;
```

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20757916/2183503

Answer (score 1):

The extension method ToTraceString() might be what you're looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring.aspx

Comment: This won't work because he's using a DbContext, which uses DbSet and DbQuery, as opposed to an ObjectContext, which uses ObjectQuery.